# Working on RUSLE for the Motagua Basin in Central America -- It is working fine until I get to the P Factor

Tags: google-earth-engine, rusle

When I get to calculating the P Factor I get the following errors

> Land Use Land Cover (LULC): Layer error: Image.clip: Parameter 'input' is required.

> P Factor: Layer error: Image.clip: Parameter 'input' is required.

Attaching the script used

```js
var CHIRPS = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD"),
    soil = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_TEXTURE-CLASS_USDA-TT_M/v02"),
    DEM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003"),
    s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2"),
    modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD12Q1");

// Defining Study Area

// Add the shape file for the Motagua Basin here

Map.addLayer(cuenca_motagua, {}, 'Cuenca Motagua');

Map.centerObject(cuenca_motagua);

// **************** R Factor ***************
var date1 = '2022-01-01';
var date2 = '2022-12-31';

// Translate the comment
// For Basin Boundary, here we will add the shape file for the Motagua Basin
// var cuenca_motagua = /* Add your shape file here */
// Map.addLayer(dataset);

// Defining dates/year
var current = CHIRPS.filterDate(date1, date2).select('precipitation').sum().clip(cuenca_motagua);
Map.addLayer(current, {}, 'Annual Rain', 0);
var R = ee.Image(current.multiply(0.363).add(79)).rename('R');
Map.addLayer(R, {min: 300, max: 900, palette: ['a52508','ff3818','fbff18','25cdff','2f35ff','0b2dab']}, 'R Factor Map', 0);

// **************** K Factor ***************
soil = soil.select('b0').clip(cuenca_motagua).rename('soil');
Map.addLayer(soil, {min: 0, max: 100, palette: ['a52508','ff3818','fbff18','25cdff','2f35ff','0b2dab']}, 'Soil', 0);

var K = soil.expression(
    "(b('soil') > 11) ? 0.0053" +
      ": (b('soil') > 10) ? 0.0170" +
        ": (b('soil') > 9) ? 0.045" +
           ": (b('soil') > 8) ? 0.050" +
            ": (b('soil') > 7) ? 0.0499" +
            ": (b('soil') > 6) ? 0.0394" +
            ": (b('soil') > 5) ? 0.0264" +
            ": (b('soil') > 4) ? 0.0423" +
            ": (b('soil') > 3) ? 0.0394" +
            ": (b('soil') > 2) ? 0.036" +
            ": (b('soil') > 1) ? 0.0341" +
            ": (b('soil') > 0) ? 0.0288" +
             ": 0"
).rename('K').clip(cuenca_motagua);

Map.addLayer(K, {min: 0, max: 0.06, palette: ['a52508','ff3818','fbff18','25cdff','2f35ff','0b2dab']}, 'KFactor Map', 0);

// **************** LS Factor ***************

var elevation = DEM.select('elevation');
var slope1 = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation).clip(cuenca_motagua);
// Converting Slope from Degrees to %
var slope = slope1.divide(180).multiply(Math.PI).tan().multiply(100);
Map.addLayer(slope, {min: 0, max: 15, palette: ['a52508','ff3818','fbff18','25cdff','2f35ff','0b2dab']}, 'slope in %', 0);

var LS4 = Math.sqrt(500 / 100);
var LS3 = ee.Image(slope.multiply(0.53));
var LS2 = ee.Image(slope).multiply(ee.Image(slope).multiply(0.076));
var LS1 = ee.Image(LS3).add(LS2).add(0.76);
var LS = ee.Image(LS1).multiply(LS4).rename("LS");

Map.addLayer(LS, {min: 0, max: 90, palette: ['a52508','ff3818','fbff18','25cdff','2f35ff','0b2dab']}, 'LS Factor Map', 0);

// **************** C Factor ***************

s2 = s2.filterDate(date1, date2).median().clip(cuenca_motagua);
var image_ndvi = s2.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename("NDVI");

Map.addLayer(image_ndvi, {min: 0, max: 0.85, palette: ['FFFFFF','CC9966','CC9900', '996600', '33CC00', '009900','006600','000000']}, 'NDVI', 0);

var alpha = ee.Number(-2);
var beta = ee.Number (1);

var C1 = image_ndvi.multiply(alpha);
var oneImage = ee.Image(1).clip(cuenca_motagua);
var C2 = oneImage.subtract(image_ndvi);
var C3 = C1.divide(C2).rename('C3');
var C4 = C3.exp();

var maxC4 = C4.reduceRegion({
  geometry: cuenca_motagua,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 3000,
  maxPixels: 475160679
});

var C5 = maxC4.toImage().clip(cuenca_motagua);
var minC4 = C4.reduceRegion({
  geometry: cuenca_motagua,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  scale: 3000,
  maxPixels: 475160679
});

var C6 = minC4.toImage().clip(cuenca_motagua);
var C7 = C4.subtract(C6);
var C8 = C5.subtract(C6);

var C = C7.divide(C8).rename('C');

Map.addLayer(C, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['FFFFFF','CC9966','CC9900', '996600', '33CC00', '009900','006600','000000']}, 'C Map', 0);

// **************** P Factor ***************

// Select land cover data from MODIS
var lulc = modis
  .filterDate(date1, date2)
  .select('LC_Type1')
  .first()
  .clip(cuenca_motagua)
  .rename('lulc');
  
Map.addLayer(lulc, {}, 'Land Use Land Cover (LULC)', 0);

// Combine LULC and slope in a single image
var lulc_slope = lulc.addBands(slope);

// Create P Factor map using an expression
var P = lulc_slope.expression(
  "(b('lulc') < 11) ? 0.8" +
    ": (b('lulc') == 11) ? 1" +
    ": (b('lulc') == 13) ? 1" +
    ": (b('lulc') > 14) ? 1" +
    ": (b('slope') < 2) and ((b('lulc')==12) or (b('lulc')==14)) ? 0.6" +
    ": (b('slope') < 5) and ((b('lulc')==12) or (b('lulc')==14)) ? 0.5" +
    ": (b('slope') < 8) and ((b('lulc')==12) or (b('lulc')==14)) ? 0.5" +
    ": (b('slope') < 12) and ((b('lulc')==12) or (b('lulc')==14)) ? 0.6" +
    ": (b('slope') < 16) and ((b('lulc')==12) or (b('lulc')==14)) ? 0.7" +
    ": (b('slope') < 20) and ((b('lulc')==12) or (b('lulc')==14)) ? 0.8" +
    ": (b('slope') > 20) and ((b('lulc')==12) or (b('lulc')==14)) ? 0.9" +
    ": 1"
).rename('P');

Map.addLayer(P, {}, 'P Factor', 0);
```

How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The [MODIS collection you're using](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MCD12Q1) is only available through 2020. When you select the first image in 2022 below, you get a missing image and the `clip` method fails.

```js
var lulc = modis
  // Returns a collection with 0 images because there are none in the range
  .filterDate(date1, date2)
  .select('LC_Type1')
  // Returns null because there is no first image
  .first()
  // Raises an error because there is no image to clip
  .clip(cuenca_motagua)
```

Using the [updated MODIS collection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MCD12Q1) that goes through 2022 should resolve this error. There may be other problems, but I wasn't able to test your code because `cuenca_motagua` was never defined.